# what is the best way to abstract endpoints?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to create endpoints that can be local in one setup and remote (via jms) in another.

What is the best approach?

I thought of creating my own component, 'abstract', then send to abstract:foo and in one setup have abstract:foo behave like direct:foo and in another setup behave like jms:queue:foo.

However, I'm not sure this is the cookbook approach and how to implement it exactly (how to do the "in one setup behave like X and in another behave like Y"), without being fragile (relying on different contents of META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/abstract in each setup)

So, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best approach was to create a bean with my own schema name and have it create the desired endpoint (DirectEndpoint or other) according to properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use the camel PropertiesComponent for this. This allows to use placeholders in endpoints. See http://camel.apache.org/properties.html

E.g.
from("{{myendpoint}}")...

You can use a properties file in setup A to define "myendpoint=direct:foo" and "myendpoint=jms:queue:foo"  in another case.